# Ldap3 python code returns only 20000 entries maximum

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap3

The below code returns only 20000 entries. How to fetch all the data from the active directory using ldap3? please help.

```
import ldap3
import pandas as pd

conn = ldap3.Connection("172.0.0.0", "CN=OSP AD,OU=Generic ID,OU=asdf,OU=asdf,DC=bundl,DC=in", "*****",
                    auto_bind=True)
conn.search("ou=swiggy,DC=bundl,DC=in", "(cn=*)", attributes=['*'], size_limit=0)
print(conn.entries)

data = conn.entries

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```